# My Gnome Online Accounts have stopped working

Tags: 22.04, evolution, online-accounts

Ubuntu 22.04, Evolution.

My GOA this morning stopped working in Evolution.

This has happened before, and I resolved it by removing the accounts and then reinstalling them.

This is not working because at the last stage of the setup, after I have verified my credentials to Google and got the 'Gnome wants to access your Google Account' dialog and clicked 'Allow', the window freezes.

Running the process via the terminal with `gnome-control-center` returns this error message:

```
** (process:2): WARNING **: 10:27:31.382: Error writing credentials to socket: Error sending message: Broken pipe
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Killed
```

So although Google has accepted the credentials, I cannot access my accounts.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no advice being forthcoming, and the only program seriously affected being Evolution, I removed Evolution, replaced it with Thunderbird, added an extension so TB communicated with Evolution Data Server, and am living happily ever after (until the next glitch 8-D).